# Customize rich editor to allow <pre> tags?

Tags: 2010, rich-text, enterprise-wiki, richhtmlfield

In a WIKI site, I'd like to allow users to input `<pre>` tags.

My goal is to use a syntax highlighter to build a small KB for he IT team. How can I setup the rich editor to easily produces snippets like this :

```
<pre class="language-powershell">
$site = Get-SPSite http://url
$owner = $site.Owner
</pre>
```

I'm using SP2010 enterprise, and the Enterprise Wiki template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SharePoint 2010 you could create a custom action to add a button to the ribbon which opens a new page to paste you source code into. Once the user closes the window some Javascript wraps the code into the `pre` tags and inserts it at the position of the cursor.

**UPDATE:** You could use combination of the `zoombldr.aspx` page (used to edit the HTML source) and JavaScript code which is used to insert a hyperlink into a Wiki page. That's how I did it (even though mine was for 2007 those haven't changed a lot). Just add a button to the ribbon via custom action which pops up the `zoombldr.aspx` page and let the user paste the source into it. Once the page is closed the JavaScript grabs the content and insert it into a wrapped `pre` element.

**UPDATE2:** AFAIK there is no official SharePoint API to insert stuff into a rich-text field. However, here's a piece of JavaScript I just gobbled together (not tested!) to open a dialog and insert the returned code into the rich-text field:

```
function RTE_InsertSourceCode(strBaseElementID)
{
    var docEditor=RTE_GetEditorDocument(strBaseElementID);
    var currentContent=new Array;
    currentContent.value="";
    currentContent.dir=docEditor.dir;
    var variables=RTE_GetEditorInstanceVariables(strBaseElementID);
    var returnValue=showModalDialog(
        variables.aSettings.urlWebRoot+'/_layouts/zoombldr.aspx',
        currentContent,
        'dialogHeight: 550px; dialogWidth:500px; help: no; status:no; resizable: yes');
    if (returnValue != "")
    {
        returnValue = "<pre class=\"language-powershell\">" + returnValue + "</pre>";
        RTE_GetSelection(strBaseElementID).pasteHTML(returnValue);
    }
    var docTextRange=docEditor.body.createTextRange();
    docTextRange.scrollIntoView(false);
    if (RTE_UseDynamicHeightSizing(strBaseElementID))
    {
        RTE_DocEditor_AdjustHeight(strBaseElementID);
    }
}
```

All you have to do now is create your custom action and you should be all set.

For SharePoint 2007 you need to hack into the rich-text editor (note: works only in IE) function `RTE_FullHtmlToolBarDefinitionFactory` to add a button to the toolbar which then does the same as above.

I've been doing that some time ago for a SharePoint 2007 Blog and Wiki using the [Google Code Prettifier](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) project and it worked so far (with some issues in old IE 6/7 browsers, though).

Comment: I'm using SP2010 enterprise, and the Enterprise Wiki template. Is there any SP specific API to inject the html tag ? or should I use a standard div-editable insertion ?

Comment: I've retagged your question if you don't mind

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I'll take a close look at this solution.

Answer (score -1):

I'd look into adding this to your webpart. It's lite weight, free, and fully customizable: http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: It might be helpful if you included some information/links about integrating ckeditor with SharePoint and how this would solve Steve's problem.